# Uploading a dynamic created image in php

Tags: php

> **To Achieve :** Resizing uploaded image and save to the filesystem

-- Suppose a 1600x1024 image is being uploaded, and the required dimension is 500x300. Thus, the solution I came to is resizing image while uploading. The code snippet is as follows :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    //print_r($_FILES); die;

    $file = $_FILES['image'];

    //print_r($file); die;

    $filename = rand().time().'.'.end(explode('.', $file['name']));

    //echo $filename; die;

    if(move_uploaded_file('"image.php?filename='.$file['tmp_name'].'"', 'uploads/'.$filename)){
        echo 'Uploaded '.$filename.' !';
    }else{
        echo 'Not Uploaded';
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

**image.php**

```
<?php
    // Filename
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $new_width = 500;
    $new_height = 200;

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Content type
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

> **Question is :** How to use move_uploaded_files in the php created image with header *Content-Type: image/jpeg*

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I think you should use `file_get_contents()` to link and after that save file to your directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the image using one of the following functions: [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), [imagegif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php), etc. If you set the second parameter to `null`, the raw image stream will be outputted directly. You need to specify image path there.

```
imagejpeg($image_p, 'new-image.jpg', 100);
```

If you want to detect image type automatically, you can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on same function or another file which you already use image.php.
I add some code on same function , is working for me please check for you.

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    //print_r($_FILES); die;

    $file = $_FILES['image'];

    //print_r($file); die;

    $filename = rand().time().'.'.end(explode('.', $file['name']));

    //echo $filename; die;

    if(move_uploaded_file('"image.php?filename='.$file['tmp_name'].'"', 'uploads/'.$filename)){
        echo 'Uploaded '.$filename.' !';

        //once your file is uploaded you converting on same image

          $filenameNew = $_GET['filename'];

        // Get new dimensions
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

        $new_width = 500;
        $new_height = 200;

        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        // Content type
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        //store path
        $imageName=rand().time()."test.jpg";
        $imagestore="uploads/".$imageName;

        // Output
        imagejpeg($image_p,$imagestore,100);

    }else{
        echo 'Not Uploaded';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
if(move_uploaded_file('"image.php?filename='.$file['tmp_name'].'"', 'uploads/'.$filename)){
    echo 'Uploaded '.$filename.' !';
}else{
    echo 'Not Uploaded';
}
```

To

```
$resized_file = "image.php?filename=".$file['tmp_name'];
$resized_file = file_get_contents($resized_file);

if(file_put_contents('uploads/'.$filename, $resized_file))
{
    echo 'Uploaded '.$filename.' !';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not Uploaded';
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents(image.php?filename=/opt/lampp/temp/phpxOgXwe): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/image/rt.php

Comment: @Sanjeev you have to provide correct path on this line `$resized_file = "image.php?filename=".$file['tmp_name'];`

Comment: @Sanjeev may be `$resized_file = "image.php?filename=".$file['name'];` works fine.

Comment: The GET parameter is used to create image with custom size, so the parameter has to be the temp location of uploaded file

Comment: @Sanjeev let the file upload first then resize it.